# How to use TOR browser as SOCKS proxy for other devices on my LAN?

Tags: socks, tor

I have installed the TOR browser on my mac and configured the networking to use port: `9150` so browsing using Safari etc uses TOR and I can test that using [the test at the Tor project test site](https://check.torproject.org/).

I would like other browsers to be able to direct their traffic via my Mac, but can’t seem to get it working.

First I tried to connect to `9150` on the Mac and use that as a socks proxy for the other device, but it does not seem to connect (no firewall configured on mac).

Next tried “Internet Sharing” from the Mac. I can connect fine, but the TOR test above fails.

What am I doing wrong / how can I achieve this?

Comment: This does not seem to have anything to do with professional server management. You should ask this on SuperUser instead.

Comment: If the configuration changes you made to Safari worked then they should work on any other browser.  So if they don't then you are skipping a step.

Comment: Tor recommends configuring as a "Transparent Proxy": https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy

Comment: Hi Ramhound, thanks for the response. Safari works on the mac that has the Tor, but on other machine that connects using web sharing it connects to the internet but not via the tor socket - does that make sense?

Comment: Hi Frank, I took a look at that link you sent me, thanks. However it says there: "Currently, transparent proxy connections are only supported for netfilter in Linux and pf in BSD" - I am using OS X - any other help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Plop! Come on guys....

Comment: you should try here:
http://tor.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

In the case of Tor Browser, Tor listens for SOCKS requests on the special loopback address `127.0.0.1` which cannot be accessed from other devices in your home network.

You can do what you want using the Tor Expert Bundle. You will need to add the following line to the Tor configuration file `torrc`:

```
SOCKSListenAddress [IP address]
```

Then configure your other devices to use the SOCKS5 proxy `[IP address]:9050`.